# Font Icon not working in blob image

Tags: svg, html5-canvas, font-awesome

This is regarding creating an image using canvas and Blob.

I am including font-icon in it as shown below. The output shows as squares instead of the icon.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
  '<text x="0" y="70" font-family="FontAwesome" font-size="70px">\uf040</text>' +
  '</svg>';

var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {
  type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

img.src = url;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <H3>SVG:</H3> 
  <svg width="100" height="100">
    <text x="0" y="70" font-family="FontAwesome" font-size="70px">&#xf040</text>
  </svg>

  <H3>Blob:</H3> 
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Am I missing something ? Can anyone help me on this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am including font-icon in it as shown below

Actually you're not including it, you are pointing to it.
Unfortunately, for security reasons, HTMLImages content must be self-dependent and can't make calls to any external resources.

This means that you'll have to really include it in your svg before you create the blob.

To do so, either copy the svg version of font-awesome directly in your svg document (only the glyphs you use need to be there) or convert one of the font files of font-awesome to a dataURI version, (achievable with xhr+FileReader) and set this dataURI as the url of your font.

Personnaly, I would go with the former since the later will produce a bigger file size.

Comment: Thank you very much Kaiido!! this was really helpful. After including the actual svg, it works.